# Calling a subroutine as part of a SQL Transaction

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, infragistics

My project is an orders application, where users can enter orders from different customers, using an `UltraGrid` to enter and edit data. When the Delete key is pressed on the keyboard, it prompts a `MsgBox` for the user to confirm they want to delete the selected row, and if so, it runs a `DELETE` query to delete that row from the database.

I also have a Save button to allow the user to save the order/changes made to the order. Ideally, I only want the row in the grid to delete temporarily as, if the user then doesn't save the order, the order line shouldn't be deleted permanently from the database.

If I put the `DELETE` query into a separate subroutine, can I then call this subroutine from my class that is saving it as part of the transaction?

This seems like it isn't going to work, as I'd not only need to call the query, but also somehow store the deleted row somewhere temporarily so that it knows which data to delete in the transaction, as well as a `Boolean` variable to tell it whether there is even any data to delete...

Are there any simpler ways of doing this? Would the above way even work?

Comment: Is this for **MS-Access** (as tagged), or for **SQL Server** (which the `tsql` tag implies)

Comment: @marc_s sorry, this is for MS-Access, I must have misused the tag not realising it was for SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted it... Nothing actually complex required at all, just needed to change the code, as below:

```
Try
   Dim Dc As New OleDbCommand
   Dim rowcode As String = ""

         rowcode = dr.Item("Product_Code").Value
```

Changed to:

```
Try
   Dim Dc As New OleDbCommand
   Dim rowcode As String = ""

         rowcode = dr.Item("Product_Code", DataRowVersion.Original)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way of doing it, is keeping all of your changes in-memory (additions, modifications and deletions) and then synchronizing them to the database when you hit your Save button.

Possibly, you'll need an AJAX action to add the operation to the server-side and a client-side script to update the row on the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Grid does not work with back-end database. It is only dealing with its local DataSource. So when you save the data back to your database check for deleted rows and preserve them.

If you want to update the local data source only on save button click you can set the grid's [UpdateMode](http://help.infragistics.com/Doc/WinForms/2016.1/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v16.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UpdateMode.html) to OnUpdate. Then you will need to call grid's [UpdateData](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBase~UpdateData.html) method. Again, this will update your local data source. How and when the local data source will update the back-end database has nothing in common with the grid. So depending on the type of your local data source you will need to handle checking for deleted rows before you send updated data back to database.

Comment: See the above edit; I've now added in the delete code in the Save query... How can I pass in the deleted data using the same `DataSet`?

Comment: If you have set UpdateMode to OnUpdate you need to call UpdateData method over UltraGrid when save button is clicked. This will update the lineset DataSet.